# Why & How C++ allows compile time arrays to be created using dynamic values

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

While writing some code, I realised one of my code works which as per my understanding shouldn't be working. The code is

```
int main() {
    int val;
    cin>>val;
    int array[val];
}
```

No only this, even the code below is also working

```
 int main() {
        int valone = rand();
        int valtwo = rand();
        int array[valone][valtwo];
    }
```

I always had the understand that static arrays needs constant values, or the values which could be deduced by compilers during compile time.

Is there any change in recent C++11/14 specification or this was true for C++ since beginning.

> NOTE: Visual Studio Compiler does gives an error in this case, but `g++` as
>   well as `clang` successfully compiles above code

Comment: C++ doesn't allow that. Maybe `s/C++/g++/`.

Comment: to avoid similar frustrations, never use gcc or clang without `-pedantic-errors` (unless you want non-portable extensions)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a [variable-length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).

These are supported by C99, and both GCC and Clang support them in C++ as a non-standard extension. (They are *not* part of the C++ language.) MSVC does not support C99, and therefore does not support them at all.

In standard C++, you would use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: to give it credit, MSVC 2015+ supports designated initializers, compound literals, and some other parts of C99 (not VLAs though), but only in C, not C++.

Answer (score 3):

This is a compiler extension called [Variable-Length Arrays](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html). This is *not* standard C++ as you said and thus should not be relied on when trying to write cross-compiler compliant code. Instead, you can use `std::vector` for "dynamic arrays", this is standard.

Answer (score 2):

There are some compilers that allow [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) as an *extension* of the language. Don't rely on it if you want portable code, use `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Variable length arrays are not standard in c++. Some compilers support it, but as non-standard extensions.

For example, see thee gcc documentation for this extension [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html#Variable-Length).

Answer (score 0):

VLA's are a very useful construct. They allow one to create an array of a size known at compile time, yet use automatic memory and not rely on dynamic memory management as vectors do.

There may be several reasons to avoid dynamic allocations, among most important would be performance penalty incurred by it (especially in multithreading scenarios) and simple lack of dynamic memory control on some MCUs.